# DriverPackageInstall tries to start to driver after install

Tags: windows-installer, dpinst

I have a driver installing using DriverPackageInstall,
this API tries to start to driver after install. I expect my driver should not try to start after install, it should start on next reboot.

Any help will appreciated.

Comment: It might help if you say why you expect a reboot to be what starts the driver. Why is it a problem if the driver can be installed and started without a reboot? Microsoft has been trying to minimize reboots for a long time!

Comment: Thanks Phil, our requirement is driver should start on boot not on install or demand start.

Comment: The reason appears to be that the DriverPackageInstall API in DIFX has no option to do what you ask. It's not obvious why this is tagged as a windows installer issue when it's DIFX problem.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't aware Driver installation is not part of windows installer part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after searching so many places, I marked driver disabled in INF file and then installed